# Are these common in America?

Tags: word-usage, american-english

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/talk-down

> [talk someone down] BRITISH to talk loudly so that other people cannot hear what someone is saying
>
> [talk someone down] INFORMAL to persuade someone to lower the price of something
>   talk down to: He wanted five thousand dollars, but I talked him down to four.

I mean it's British,so is it used in America as well? Is it common?(first use)

And what is the alternative for the first use?

Comment: The second use is common in the US, but not the first.

Comment: Then of course, there's *talking someone down* in the sense of persuading them not to do something. Or to *talk someone down* as in say bad things about them to other people (though that is arguably ditransitive).

Comment: What can be an alternative for the first one?@Davo

Comment: Is this use common as well: He's been talking you down all this time.(saying bad things about you). As SamBC said in AmE?

Comment: I don't recognise the first usage (as a native BrEng speaker). It isn't common in the British English either.  There is an expression "to shout someone down", which has roughly that meaning.

Comment: SamBC - "there's talking someone down in the sense of persuading them not to do something." - British police officers try to do this to suicidal people on ledges or bridges.

Comment: @Davo what will be an alternative for the first use in AmE?

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish I don't know of a common idiom for that. We just say "I got him to speak more softly" or something.

Comment: "Shouting down" is a common alternative in US English.

Answer (score 1):

The first use is not common in American English. The second use is common.

The first use is also not common in British English. There is a related expression in both US and British English: "Shouting down" or "To shout someone down" meaning to prevent a person from speaking by shouting out and interrupting:

> The MP stood up to defend the government's policy, but the angry crowd shouted him down.